# How to make Java Web Server keep sending response to the HTML web page?

Tags: java, webserver

Below is a sample code snippet that generates web server in Java and prints Hello World in the browser when user visits 127.0.0.1:8080 in a browser.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleWebServer {

    Socket remote;
    ServerSocket s;

    /**
     * WebServer constructor.
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    protected void start() throws IOException {      
      try {
        s = new ServerSocket(8080);
        
        System.out.println("Webserver starting up on port 8080");
        System.out.println("(press ctrl-c to exit)");
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        return;
      }

      for (;;) {
        try {
            remote = s.accept();
            
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(remote.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(remote.getOutputStream());

            String str = ".";
            while (!str.equals("")) {
                str = in.readLine();
            }

            out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
            out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            out.println("Server: Bot");
            // this blank line signals the end of the headers
            out.println("");
            // Send the HTML page
            out.println("Hello World");
            out.flush();
            
            remote.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
      }
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   * @throws java.io.IOException
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    SimpleWebServer ws = new SimpleWebServer();
    ws.start();
  }
}
```

Is it posible to make the server keep sending response to the browser without having user keep refreshing the page? lets say keep showing incrementing number (not appending data on the page).

I am not looking for WebSocket solution, but Web Server in Java.

Comment: Yes, you *are* looking for a WebSocket solution. Or a javascript solution, that continually polls the server for new data and updates the page, which is just a worse WebSocket solution with more overhead and less functionality.

Comment: You can also try responding with below head in html. I believe browser still supports this:
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>

Your soocket.accept is questionable though (and some other room for improvements like try-resource or not swallowing the stacktrace). You may want to make it threaded